# Making a karaf/docker service read a configuration file

Tags: docker, karaf

Starting from the io8 maven archetype, I'm setting up a Docker container containing a Karaf container containing a CXF restful web service.

I want this to read a file when it starts up that parameterizes it. What's the procedure for setting up (a) a Docker container so that it can receive a config file when launched, and (b) finding that file from inside?

Comment: The easiest way would be to use a volume.

Answer (score 1):

To provide a configuration file to a container you can use something like the following:
`docker run -d -v /path/to/your/config.file:/path/inside/the/container/config.file yourimage`

For more information please refer the official documentation on [how to use volumes](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/).